# IReadOnlyList<T> to BindingList

Tags: c#, list

I'm trying to bind a `IReadOnlyList` of a `Material` class I made to a `ComboBox` but I can't find a way to make this works.

```
var bList = new BindingList<Material>(listToBind);
```

This gives me `Argument type 'System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<Data.Material>' is not assignable to parameter type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<Data.Material>'`

Do I need to cast it to `IList` or is there any other way to accomplish this ?

Comment: From where you get the IReadOnlyList? Can you get directly a List? If not, i think you should iterate over the readonly adding the elements to a List.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BindingList<T>` does not have a constructor that takes any of the interfaces an `IReadOnlyList` extends.

`BindingList<T>` has two constructors ([MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679(v=vs.110).aspx)), one is empty, and the other takes an `IList<T>`. However, `IReadOnlyList<T>` extends `IEnumerable<T>`, which means it provides the function `.ToList()` that gives us a `List<T>` that we can use to populate our `BindingList<T>`.

The final code would then look like this:

```
var bList = new BindingList<Material>(listToBind.ToList());
```

Comment: Note this only works when including `using System.Linq` in your code file

Answer (score 0):

In MSDN:

> BindingList(IList)
>   Initializes a new instance of the BindingList class with the specified list.

So you need an object which implements IList; IReadOnlyList does not.

You could achive what you want with the following code:

```
var bList = new BindingList<Material>(listToBind.ToList());
```